# XSLT Compare Date to a Date portion of DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm attempting to make an XML log file a bit more readable via XSLT.

It has several events within the log and the times are in dateTime format and would like to select the events which occurred on a specific (single) date.

Here is an excerpt from my `log.xml` file:

```
  <event>
    <bag>168</bag>
    <action>Check Out</action>
    <time>2011-04-07T11:41:34.7219171-04:00</time>
    <user>jroderick</user>
  </event>

  <event>
    <bag>168</bag>
    <action>Check In</action>
    <time>2011-04-07T11:41:38.7079901-04:00</time>
    <user>jroderick</user>
  </event>

  <event>
    <bag>1147</bag>
    <action>Check In</action>
    <time>2011-04-07T14:27:14.0662271-04:00</time>
    <user>jholby</user>
  </event>
```

In my `log.xsl` I have the following for the table I want to generate: one row per event.

```
<xsl:for-each select="log/event">
    <xsl:if test="???">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="user"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="time"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="action"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
```

I was hoping there was a rather simplistic way to achieve this in the 2.0 functions but I haven't been able to locate anything.

Attempted to cast the dateTime into an xs:date but without any luck using Saxon 9.3 HE for .Net.

http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each
             select="log/event[
                        xs:date(xs:dateTime(time))
                      eq
                        xs:date('2011-04-07-04:00')
                     ]">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="user"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="time"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="action"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<result>
    <tr>
        <td>jroderick</td>
        <td>2011-04-07T11:41:34.7219171-04:00</td>
        <td>Check Out</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>jroderick</td>
        <td>2011-04-07T11:41:38.7079901-04:00</td>
        <td>Check In</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>jholby</td>
        <td>2011-04-07T14:27:14.0662271-04:00</td>
        <td>Check In</td>
    </tr>
</result>
```

**Note**: Your data is in `xs:dateTime` format, so you need to cast first as this. **Do take care of time zone**

Comment: Ack I should have thought to initially cast to xs:dateTime. Awesome Alej!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to select based on the date, and you are sure the date format is always going to be in that format, how about just working with strings? Saves you having to worry about DateTime etc.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//event[substring(time,1,10) = '2011-04-07']">
 <xsl:value-of select="user"/> ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

you can even go as far as to create a template, and pass the date in using with-param if you're going to use it in a couple of places.